# How to implement close a subview when user touched its superview in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, view, uiviewcontroller, subview

I have a view controller and I have created an another view in same view controller and added it as a sub view.When a button clicked the subview will appear and it takes half of the screen.How can I close the subview when user touched the superview(main view in background) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a gesture recognizer and on a single tap action on the superview call removeFromSuperview on the subview.

In your viewDidLoad add something like this:

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];

    [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [mainView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

And then add the function:

```
- (void) handleSingleTap: (id) sender
{

    [secondView removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Comment: I used this method, but when user touches on the subview also it is going to remove from the superview.But I want to remove the subview only when user touches its mainview.How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

For more control of when you want the subview to be removed, you could override the mainViewController's responder method like so:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [subview removeFromSuperView];
}
```

This way you can actually see where in the screen the user tapped, and respond accordingly.